# How can import an audio (.wav) file into R?

Tags: r

```
#Read a Wave File
library(readr)
library(tuneR)
#path of file
file_audio_path <- "file_example.wav"
#Read Files
train_audio = readWave(file_audio_path)
#Lets see the structure of the audio.
str(train_audio)
```

So I run it and I get this error:

```
Error in readWave(file_audio_path) : 
  File 'file_example.wav' does not exist.
```

My question is how do I make it so that it recognizes the audio file I have in my folder. How do I make R recognize the path?

Comment: R will look for files in the current working directory. You can find the current working directory by running `getwd()`. Is that the same folder where your wav file is stored? If so, does it show up if you run `list.files()`? If your file is in some other directory, you can either specify the full path  or change your working directory with `setwd()`

Comment: You can use `file.choose()` to search for the folder containing your file. The function will return the full path to the file.